# Javascript/jquery Speed in Internet Explorer - Ajax Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, pagespeed

I am trying to increase the speed on IE for the following javascript code on my page:

http://www.ufs.unsw.edu.au/gpa

I have created another version of this by searching on internet about some tips to increase the speed of Javascript

http://www.ufs.unsw.edu.au/gpa-fast

Instead of storing values in a string, I have used an array in to store values in a loop and used array.join to show those values on page.

```
function ajaxQuery($obj)
  {
      var domObj=[], i=0;
      var startEXP="<div class='notesclick'><div><img src='img/notes.png' width='25' height='25' alt='notes'></div><div class='notes'><ul>";
     var endEXP="</ul></div></div>";
      $obj.find('Course').each(function(){

          var course=$(this);
                    var Code = course.attr("ACAD");
                    var Bof = course.attr("Name");
                    var Yrs = course.attr("Duration");
                    var S2= course.attr("S2Entry");
                    var Stream = course.attr("FSstream"); 
                    var GPA = course.attr("GPA"); 
                    var English = course.attr("EngGrade");                      var addNotes=startEXP;

                    //find notes
                    $(this).find('Note').each(function(){

                        var Notes=$(this).attr("Text");

                        addNotes=addNotes+"<li>"+Notes+"</li>";


                        });
                addNotes=addNotes+endEXP;

                if(addNotes==startEXP+endEXP)
                {
                    addNotes="&nbsp;";
                }

                if(S2=="Y")
                {
                S2="<span class='red'>+</span>";    
                }else
                {
                    S2="";
                }

    domObj[i]='<tr><td>'+Code+' '+S2+'</td><td>'+Bof+'</td><td>'+Yrs+'</td><td>'+Stream+'</td><td>'+GPA+'</td><td>'+English+'</td><td>'+addNotes+'</td></tr>';          

    i++;

    /*$('#gpa tbody').append('<tr><td>'+Code+' '+S2+'</td><td>'+Bof+'</td><td>'+Yrs+'</td><td>'+Stream+'</td><td>'+GPA+'</td><td>'+English+'</td><td>'+addNotes+'</td></tr>');  */

  }); //end course

  $('table#gpa tbody').append(domObj.join(""));

     }
```

and above function is being called from function init() which is given below:

```
function init($xml, Yeari, Facultyi, oTable)
        {
            var Year=Yeari, Faculty=Facultyi, tabArr=[], i=0;

            //init table            

            //console.log("Table is "+oTable);
            //alert(Faculty+" "+Year);


            if(Faculty=="all")
            {
                oTable.fnClearTable(); //clear previous table
                //console.log("all");
            $('#gpa tbody').empty();    
            $xml.find("Year[Year='"+Year+"']").find('Faculty').each(function(){
                ////console.log("Faculty "+$(this).attr("Name"));
                ajaxQuery($(this)); 


 }); //end faculty
```

And below is the main function from where init() is being called:

```
$(document).ready(function(){        




     $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../loader/UNSW_UGRAD_COURSE_DATA.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                ////console.log("Reading Success");
                var oTable=$('#gpa').dataTable( {
    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 30, 50, 100, -1], [10, 30, 50, 100, "All"]],
    "iDisplayLength" : -1,
    "oLanguage": {
"sSearch": "Search by keyword" 
}
  });
                init( $(xml), 2014, "all", oTable);
                streamChanger();

                $('#year_btn').on("change", function(){
                setYears($(xml), oTable);   
                streamChanger();                
                }); 

            $('#faculty_btn').on("change", function(){
                setOptions($(xml), oTable);     
                                                                           streamChanger();                             

                   });                  
                },
                error:function(){
                alert("Reading failed");
  }

     }); //end ajax function    


    }); /* end ready */
```

But when I load it in IE, it still takes almost the same amount of time as gpa page.
Can somebody advise me how I can improve the speed of this page please?

Comment: Before posting, it is a good idea to reduce your example to the minimum required to display the issue. That way others can focus on fixing your issue rather than trying to find it.

Comment: Hi RobG,I have now edited the post so that people can focus on code.

Comment: The string concatenation trick just speeds up the concatenation part. It will help when you have say more than 100 strings to concatenate but not much help otherwise. DOM table manipulation in IE is slow, the jQuery code for append is tortuous, I don't know how it does it. It may wrap the HTML in tags to create a full table, then insert it in a temporary div or similar, then bring the child nodes (TRs, TDs etc. as appropriate) into the target table. At least it seems to do that for some things.